# How to get a list of lint rules only for dart or analyser in specific version?

Tags: flutter, dart, static-analysis, sourceanalyser

I use the `Analyzer` package in my project to perform a static code analysis and modify some rules.

For each version of this package (or dart version), How can I find the total list of rules already defined?

I found this site: https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/index.html but it's not associated with a version. (May be correspond to the latest ?)

For example, I use `analyzer` package in version `3.2.0`.
How I can see all rules defines only for this version 3.2.0` ? (without my custom rules).